# Copy "Artist" into "Album Artist" in iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, metadata

In iTunes, Is there a way to automatically populate the "Album Artist" metadata with the "Artist" information, for all songs where the "Album Artist" field is empty?

Obviously this is for songs from various artists. This is easy to do manually, but it gets tedious quick.

The reason why I want to do that is that on the iPhone, the field "Artist" under "Library" refers to the field "Album Artist". The song where this field is not populated are not listed under the artist name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A third-party application (or AppleScript) is needed to do this “automatically”.

You can run an application like Bliss (blisshq.com) in the background to scan your library periodically and make the changes to update missing tags.